# App Store Guidelines in-app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am developing an app for an author who wrote a book helping people to communicate better. The book contains some exercises. The author wants an app, with which the customer can do these exercises on the go.

The author wants:

- A trial version with limited amount of exercises
- A possibility to buy all exercises using in-app purchase
- Customers who bought the book should be able to unlock all exercises without paying.

This is easy to do on a technical level, however does anyone have some experience if apple allows an app with such behaviour? The apple guidelines say:

> 3.1.4 Content Codes: Apps may not use their own mechanisms to unlock content or functionality, such as license keys, augmented reality markers, QR codes, etc. In limited circumstances, such as when features are dependent upon specific hardware to function, the app may unlock that functionality without using in-app purchase (e.g. an astronomy app that adds features when synced with a telescope). App features that work in combination with an approved physical product (such as a toy) on an optional basis may unlock functionality without using IAP, provided that an IAP option is available as well. You may not, however, require users to purchase unrelated products or engage in advertising or marketing activities to unlock app functionality.

I am not sure how to interpret them in case of the book.

Answer (score 0):

I think your fine for this case.

If you provide a way for users to pay in the app and also provide a way to get that same content for free you should be fine. Buying the product is optional. You can unlock by paying in app, or buying the product.

I think that is what they mean by:

> App features that work in combination with an approved physical
>   product (such as a toy) on an optional basis may unlock functionality
>   without using IAP, provided that an IAP option is available as well.